# Performance decreases when there is huge amount of data in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, performance

In my angular application, there is a parent-child relation.In child we are having a reactive form.

whenever we make any changes in the form all the changes get reflected in the parent too.

But performance decreases when there are lot of data available in the parent. May be it is taking time to detect changes or something else.

I have tried to detach that component from the tree  and use OnPush strategy  but it is not making any difference in the performance.

Performance is fine when there are less number of data in the parent.

How can i enhance the performance of the application in such case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a "huge" amount of data? Please also share some of your code.

Comment: There's definitely not enough info to help you there

Comment: Could you try to make a small repro on stackblitz of your current architecture? (with mocked data maybe)